# How would you reference json data in a view?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I want to add the 'msg' data returned from my controller in my view

In my controller I have:

```
render json: { notice: 'Reply sent.', from: @message.from, msg: @message.content }
```

In my view I have

```
<script>
$('.new_short_message').bind('ajax:success', function() {
        $( this ).before( '<p>message</p>' );
    });
</script>
```

How do I reference the 'msg' data in place of the `'<p>message</p>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function of the `ajax:success` handler takes three arguments (`xhr`, `data` and `status`), of which `data` contains the transferred data. It is a plain JSON object, so you can access the contents directly with `data.notice`, `data.from`, and so on. For example:

```
$('.new_short_message').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
  $(this).before('<p>'+data.msg+'</p>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I left out the parameters in function(xhr, data, status) part